How to indent a heading under a numbered list in Rmarkdown knitting to HTML?
I have this Rmarkdown file:
---
title: "Indent heading under list"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## This is a heading

1. I have some numbered list items under this heading

2. And I want to have sub-heading under this numbered listed

3. Under this new sub-heading, I want to have tabs under it

### Sub-heading I want {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

#### Apple

- This is an apple

#### Orange

- This is an orange

###

4. I want the above sub-heading to have indentation so that it is indented under item number 3 above

Which is currently like this:

As explained in the Rmarkdown itself, I want to have indentation of the sub-heading under the numbered list, so that it will look like this:

Most resources I found online recommend manually indenting the heading(s) with four spaces under the numbered list, but that doesn't work (see attached screenshot).


If you add an indented hyphen before the ### then this creates an indented sub-header. But then there's a bullet, I don't know how to get rid of this one (Edit: now I know; see at bottom).
---
title: "Indent heading under list"
output: html_document
---


## This is a heading

1. I have some numbered list items under this heading

2. And I want to have sub-heading under this numbered listed

3. Under this new sub-heading, I want to have tabs under it

  - ### Sub-heading I want 

    - And I also want an apple



EDIT
Here is a CSS way to remove the bullet.
First, assign a HTML class, say nobullet to the subheader:
3. Under this new sub-heading, I want to have tabs under it

  - ### Sub-heading I want {.nobullet}

    - And I also want an apple

Now, add this CSS somewhere, e.g. at the beginning of the document:
<style>
li:has(.nobullet) {list-style-type: none;}
</style>


2nd EDIT
Here is a simpler solution, and this one works with the tabs.
---
title: "Indent heading under list"
output: html_document
---

<style>
.indented {padding-left: 100px;}
</style>

## This is a heading

1. I have some numbered list items under this heading

2. And I want to have sub-heading under this numbered listed

3. Under this new sub-heading, I want to have tabs under it

### Sub-heading I want {.indented .tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

#### Apple 

  - And I also want an apple

#### Orange

  - This is an orange


### 

4. I want the above sub-heading to have indentation so that it is indented under item number 3 above



Does it remove the heading bullet if you do - ### Sub-heading I want {.nobullet} and then add the css .ul.nobullet {list-style: none;}?

SamR> I didn't try, but this is surely doable with CSS.

Agreed - I think that syntax is correct but if not the essential point is it give it a class and make sure elements of that class AND the class ul do not have a bullet. It might need an !important at the end of it to make sure it's not overridden by the existing markdown css rules.

SamR> Your CSS is not correct. The li (= the bullet) is a parent of the subheader. See my edit.

Thank you for the answer, however the tabs (under the sub-heading) are quite important in my case which don't work with a hyphen. Do you have any idea on how to preserve that?

@benson23 I've found a solution. Please see my second edit.

I believe that this isn't possible in R Markdown. A possible solution could be to switch to Quarto, which allows to use divs to mark tabsets:
3. Under this new sub-heading, I want to have tabs under it

   ::: {.panel-tabset}

   #### Apple

   - This is an apple

   #### Orange

   - This is an orange

   :::

4. I want the above sub-heading to have indentation so that it is indented under item number 3 above



If you want something to be part of the list item, in markdown you need to indent it beyond the list marker. Thus indent it either three or four spaces:
2. And I want to have sub-heading under this numbered listed

3. Under this new sub-heading, I want to have tabs under it

   ### Sub-heading I want

   #### Apple

   - This is an apple

   #### Orange

   - This is an orange

4. I want the above sub-heading to have indentation so that it is indented under item number 3 above


Thank you for your answer. This is actually the first thing I tried before posting here, but that doesn't work in my case (see updated post for screenshot).

@benson23 I don't know about R-Markdown, but it works in plain pandoc
